# Vector function on Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, vectorization

I want to calculate frequency of a word in a sentence. My dataframe has a "Title" column which contains a sentence (String) in each row. This is my current approach:

```
# num times queryWord is in sentence / num words in sentence
list = df['Title'].str.count(queryWord) / len(df['Title'].str.split())
```

However, `len(df['Title'].str.split())` returns the length of the "Title" column rather than the length of the array that is generated by split() in each row. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
list = df['Title'].str.count(queryWord) / df['Title'].str.split().str.len()
```

`df['Title'].str.split()` returns a `pd.Series` of `list` objects. That's why this question was marked as a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks, that did it. What is the meaning of .str?

Comment: Glad it worked, please accept the answer.
In pandas, the `Series` object has string methods which you can access via `.str.method_name`. The reason you have to access them that way is that some of them have the same name as another method that has a different use. Examples of this are `pd.Series.str.replace` which does not work the same way as `pd.Series.replace` and `pd.Series.str.get` which does not work the same way as `pd.Series.get`